# Will moving existing Achievements to a Group make old app version malfunction?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, game-center

I have an existing app that's already released to the public which has a "single app" game center entry with many achievements.

Now i'm adding a new app with which I want the original app to share achievements. So there's a "Move to Group" button in my original app where I can transfer my achievements to a new Group. This process requires me to change the achievement ids to prepend "grp." to them.

If I do this, will it screw up the people who already have the old version installed? Or will the versions of the app that are already released will keep the original achievement ids?

Comment: My experience is there's no problem. I joined two apps' leaderboards and the old versions kept working fine.

Comment: But did the id's change for the leaderboards?

Comment: This may be the answer to your question> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349710/when-i-update-my-game-in-itunes-connect-will-the-leaderboards-carry-over

Comment: Nope that was addressing something different, but I found my answer by trying it, since nobody seemed to have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Achievements will continue to work, but they will be reset for all existing users of the old version of the app. Any achievements that users of the old version had will be gone.