# when i update my game in iTunes connect will the leaderboards carry over?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

if i update my game in iTunes connect will the leaderboards and achievements carry over.

i have left everything related to game center the same in the new update but iTunes connect says "You don't have any new leaderboards for this app"

just wondering if i need to make and integrate a new leaderboard for the update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR: Yes, they'll transfer.**

When you submit an update for your app, any existing leaderboards and achievements that have been approved in previous versions *will* carry over to the new version.

The reason it says "You don't have any new leaderboards for this app" is because you probably haven't added any leaderboards *in addition to* the leaderboards previously approved.